# Detect problematic nodes on network using a list of paths with weight

Tags: python, networking, graph, networkx

I'm trying to detect problematic/slow nodes in a network, for this, I'm having a list of paths between nodes and how many errors or retransmissions took to send a message to a destination. For example:

```
[
    {'path':['a', 'c', 'e', 'z'], 'errors': 0},
    ...
    {'path':['a', 'b', 'd', 'z'], 'errors': 4},
    {'path':['a', 'c', 'd', 'z'], 'errors': 4},
    ...
    {'path':['a', 'b', 'e', 'z'], 'errors': 0}
]
```

In theory, I have all the possible paths between nodes and their respective delays. So with this data, I want to detect 'problematic nodes'. In the previous example, there were several paths, but all paths that pass through the **d** node will have more delay, so this node (and others similar to it) must be pinpointed as problematic.

**Is there any known algorithm to solve this problem?**

My naive approach was to use the error counter for every path and add those counter to every node at the path, and then when all the paths/nodes are processed, divide the error counter by the number of neighbors this node has. But that doesn't give me a good result, showing different nodes as problematic.

A code example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random


def get_problematic_nodes(path_list):
    node_connections = {}
    node_counter_dict = {}
    for e in path_list:
        value = 0
        if e['retransmits'] > 1:
            value = 1

        path_len = len(e['path'])
        for i in xrange(path_len):
            node = e['path'][i]
            if node not in node_counter_dict:
                node_counter_dict[node] = value
            else:
                node_counter_dict[node] += value

            if node not in node_connections:
                node_connections[node] = set()

            # previous node
            if i - 1 >= 0:
                node_connections[node].add(e['path'][i - 1])

            # next node
            if i + 1 <= path_len - 1:
                node_connections[node].add(e['path'][i + 1])

    nodes_score = {}

    print "Link size for every node:"
    for k, v in node_connections.items():
        link_number = len(v)
        print "Node: {} links:{}".format(k, link_number)
        nodes_score[k] = node_counter_dict[k]/link_number

    print "\nHeuristic score for every node:"
    for k,v in nodes_score.items():
        print "Node: {} score:{}".format(k, v)

    max_score_node_key = max(node_counter_dict.iterkeys(), key=(lambda key: node_counter_dict[key]/len(node_connections[key]) ))
    print "\nMax scored node: {}".format(max_score_node_key)

edge_list = [
    ('host1', 'leaf1'),
    ('host2', 'leaf2'),
    ('leaf1', 'spine1'),
    ('leaf1', 'spine2'),
    ('leaf2', 'spine1'),
    ('leaf2', 'spine2'),
    ('spine1', 'vmx8'),
    ('spine1', 'vmx9'),
    ('spine2', 'vmx8'),
    ('spine2', 'vmx9'),
    ('vmx8', 'vmx7'),
    ('vmx9', 'vmx7'),
    ('spine3', 'vmx8'),
    ('spine3', 'vmx9'),
    ('spine4', 'vmx8'),
    ('spine4', 'vmx9'),
    ('leaf3', 'spine3'),
    ('leaf3', 'spine4'),
    ('leaf4', 'spine3'),
    ('leaf4', 'spine4'),
    ('host3', 'leaf3'),
    ('host4', 'leaf4'),
]

# prepare graph
G = nx.Graph()
for e in edge_list:
    G.add_edge(*e)

# define problematic nodes
test_problem_nodes = ['spine3']

# generate the paths. Paths that touches problematic nodes have more retransmits
test_path_list = []
hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3', 'host4']
for h1 in hosts:
    for h2 in hosts:
        if h1 == h2:
            continue

        all_paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, h1, h2)
        for path in all_paths:
            retransmits = 0
            if len(set(path).intersection(set(test_problem_nodes))) > 0:
                retransmits = 10

            test_path_list.append({
                'src': h1,
                'dst': h2,
                'path': path,
                'retransmits': retransmits
                })

# nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
# plt.draw()
# plt.show()

get_problematic_nodes(test_path_list)
```

Comment: I would start by googling the term "network centrality".  There are lots ways to calculate different types of 'centrality', and probably a few of them are well-suited for what you're after.

Comment: I disagree with @Joel. Network centrality measures would help if he had a weights on individual connections. He does, however, have weights (here transmission errors) on full paths. It will be hard to use the centrality measures implemented in networkx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to normalize your error count by the number of observed paths. Changing `get_problematic_nodes` to

```
def get_problematic_nodes(event_list):
    numerator = dict()
    denominator = dict()
    for event in event_list:
        for node in event['path']:
            try:
                numerator[node] += event['retransmits']
                denominator[node] += 1
            except KeyError:
                numerator[node] = event['retransmits']
                denominator[node] = 1

    node_score = {node : numerator[node] / denominator[node] for node in numerator.keys()}

    print "\nHeuristic score for every node:"
    for k,v in node_score.items():
        print "Node: {} score:{}".format(k, v)

    max_score = None
    for k,v in node_score.items():
        if v > max_score:
            max_score_node_key = k
            max_score = v
    print "\nMax scored node: {}".format(max_score_node_key)
```

yields:

```
Heuristic score for every node:
Node: vmx9 score:8
Node: vmx8 score:8
Node: host1 score:7
Node: vmx7 score:7
Node: spine1 score:7
Node: leaf4 score:8
Node: spine3 score:10
Node: spine2 score:7
Node: leaf1 score:7
Node: spine4 score:7
Node: leaf3 score:8
Node: leaf2 score:7
Node: host3 score:8
Node: host4 score:8
Node: host2 score:7

Max scored node: spine3
```